# Casting an object to a subset of of its bases

Tags: c++, casting, multiple-inheritance, template-meta-programming

I have a class defined as follows:

```
template< typename... >
class Base;

template< typename T >
class Base<T>{
  //pure virtual functions dependent on T
public:
  virtual ~Base() = default;
};

template< typename... Ts >
class Base<Ts...>
 : public Base<Ts>...
{  
  //empty
};
```

The questions are:

- Is there a way to cast `Base< T1, T2, T3 >&` to `Base< T2, T3 >&`?
- Is there a way to cast `Base< T1, T2, T3 >&` to `Base< T2, T1, T3 >&`?

**EDIT:**
Let me rephrase the question without the templates.
I have a class defined as follows:

```
class Base_int{
public:
  virtual int f() = 0;
  virtual ~Base_int() = default;
};
class Base_float{
public:
  virtual float f() = 0;
  virtual ~Base_float() = default;
};
class Base_double{
public:
  virtual double f() = 0;
  virtual ~Base_double() = default;
};

class IFD 
: public Base_int
, public Base_float
, public Base_double
{  };

class IF
: public Base_int
, public Base_float
{  };

class FID
: public Base_float
, public Base_int
, public Base_double
{  };
```

The questions are:

- Is there a way to cast `IFD&` to `IF&`?
- Is there a way to cast `IFD&` to `FID&`?

**EDIT 2:**
To further clarify:
I'm impementing a generic visitor pattern implementation which I will be using in a generic tree container. I'm using the mixin (CRTP) pattern to implement `accept` method of visited classes as well as `visit` method of visitors. These methods are virtual and I need the hierarchy I posted in the OP.
There is a base class called `IVisitor<Ts...>` that implements an interface of the visitor that visits `Ts...`. This interface is composed of classes `IVisitor<T>` - just as in the OP.
A concrete visitor that implements the `IVisitor<Ts...>` is defined as follows:

```
class ConcreteVisitor : public IVisitor<T1, T2, T2, ...>{
  //Implementation of the visit methods defined in IVisitor<Ts...>
  virtual void visit( T1& v ) override { /*...*/ }
  virtual void visit( T2& v ) override { /*...*/ }
  virtual void visit( T3& v ) override { /*...*/ }
}
```

It occurred to me that it would be useful if the ConcreteVisitor could visit stuff in the `IVisitor<Us...>` where `Us...` is a subset, or a permutation of `Ts...`. In order to do that, I need to cast it to that base - hence the question.

Comment: `Base< T1, T2, T3 >` does not inherit from `Base< T2, T3 >` neither from `Base< T2, T1, T3 >`. You should cast only to classes the object is implementing to avoid undefined behaviour...

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the Mixin pattern?

Comment: My state is still valid... `IFD` does not inherit from `IF` so you should not cast reference of `IFD` to `IF`. The same applies to `FID`. What exactly you want to achieve? Cause maybe there is some other way to do it...

Comment: If you're asking if the compiler will let you `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` between classes that aren't related by inheritance or cast operators, the answer is no.

If you're asking whether it's safe to `reinterpret_cast` between identical classes, the answer is yes, but only if virtual methods are nowhere involved.

If you're asking if you can define a conversion operator between one class template instantiation and the same template instantiated with any permutation of any subset of the class's template arguments, then in principle probably, and I would love to see what it looked like.

Comment: @acwaters `reinterpret_cast` is still risky as the order of inheritance is different...

Comment: @W.F. He didn't mention any data members in any of the `Base<T>` specializations; if they contained no data and no virtual methods, then they would all be layout-compatible, and `reinterpret_cast`ing between any of them -- and, by extension, between any of the variadic specializations -- would be perfectly safe.

Comment: @acwaters you're right with no data and no virtual methods stuff, but in this scenario I think Mixin pattern could give the same effect and no undefined behaviour future risks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After examining the problem some more I realized that what I needed a wrapper that adapts generic visitors to my interfaces. This is the solution I went with - see the `IVisitable::adaptVisitor` static method:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>

 //Visitable base class
template< typename  >
class Visitable;

  //Visitable class interface
template< typename... >
class IVisitor;

  //Assures that the visitor type derives from IVisitor
template< typename IVisitor_type >
class IVisitable
 : public IVisitable<typename IVisitor_type::derives_from_IVisitor>
{  };

  //Implements the Visitor adapter
template< typename Derived, typename Root, typename... Ts >
class VisitorWrapper;

  //IVisitable base class
template< typename... Ts >
class IVisitable< IVisitor<Ts...> >{
public:
    //Visitor interface type
  using IVisitor = IVisitor<Ts...>;

    //Visitor adapter type
  template< typename F >
  class VisitorAdapter;

    //Helper function
  template< typename F >
  static VisitorAdapter<F&&> adaptVisitor( F&& f )
  { return { std::forward<F>(f) }; }

    //Accept visitor pure virtual methods
  virtual void accept( IVisitor&  )       = 0;
  virtual void accept( IVisitor&  ) const = 0;
  virtual void accept( IVisitor&& )       = 0;
  virtual void accept( IVisitor&& ) const = 0;

protected:
  virtual ~IVisitable() = default;
};

  //Implements the visitor adapter of F class
template< typename... Ts >
template< typename F >
class IVisitable<IVisitor<Ts...>>::VisitorAdapter
  : public VisitorWrapper< VisitorAdapter<F>, ::IVisitor<Ts...>, Ts... >
      //Derives from VisitorWrapper that implements all of the virtual methods
{
public:
  template< typename U >
  void visit( U&& u ){ f( std::forward<U>(u) ); }

  VisitorAdapter( F f_ ) : f(f_) {  }

  F f;
};

  //Basic IVisitor of T
template< typename T >
class IVisitor<T>{
public:
  using derives_from_IVisitor = IVisitor;

  virtual void visit(       T& )  = 0;
  virtual void visit( const T& )  = 0;

  virtual ~IVisitor()              = default;
};

  //IVisitor of Ts derives from Visitor<T>
template< typename T, typename... Ts >
struct IVisitor<T, Ts...>
 : IVisitor<T>, IVisitor<Ts...>
{
  using derives_from_IVisitor = IVisitor;
};

  //Visitable base class. Final to prevent errors
template< typename Derived >
struct Visitable final
{
    //Extends class wraps the Base class inheritance
  template< typename Base >
  class extends : public Base
  {
  public:
      //Propagate the IVisitor interface.
    using IVisitor = typename Base::IVisitor;

      //Prevents incomprehensible errors when visitor doesn't
      //define Derived as its visited class
    static_assert(
      std::is_base_of<::IVisitor<Derived>, IVisitor>::value
    , "Base class visitor interface does not support visitation of this type"
    );

    //Implement accept method via CRTP
    virtual void accept( IVisitor& v ) override{
      static_cast< ::IVisitor<Derived>& >(v).visit(     // Disambiguation
        static_cast<Derived&>(*this)                    // CRTP
      );
    }
    virtual void accept( IVisitor& v ) const override {
      static_cast< ::IVisitor<Derived>& >(v).visit(     // Disambiguation
         static_cast<const Derived&>(*this)             // CRTP
      );
    }
    virtual void accept( IVisitor&& v ) override{
      static_cast< ::IVisitor<Derived>&& >(v).visit(    // Disambiguation
         static_cast<Derived&>(*this)                   // CRTP
      );
    }

    virtual void accept( IVisitor&& v ) const override{
      static_cast< ::IVisitor<Derived>&& >(v).visit(    // Disambiguation
        static_cast<const Derived&>(*this)              // CRTP
      );
    }
  protected:
    virtual ~extends() = default;
  };

  ~Visitable() = delete;
};

template< typename > struct print_type;

//Uses CRTP to implement visit method of IVisitor
//Consumes the list of Ts... so that the inheritance hierarchy is linear
template<
  typename Derived  //  CRTP
, typename... Rs    //  Base class (IVisitor<Rs...>)
, typename T        //  Currently implemented type
, typename... Ts    //  The rest of types
>  class VisitorWrapper< Derived, IVisitor<Rs...>, T, Ts... >
 : public VisitorWrapper< Derived, IVisitor<Rs...>, Ts... >  //Consume T
{
    //Cast to Derived and call visit method
  virtual void visit(       T& v ){ static_cast<Derived*>(this)->visit(v); }
  virtual void visit( const T& v ){ static_cast<Derived*>(this)->visit(v); }
};

//Uses CRTP to implement visit method of IVisitor
template< typename Derived, typename... Rs, typename T >
class VisitorWrapper< Derived, IVisitor<Rs...>, T >
 : public IVisitor<Rs...>  //IVisitor<Ts...>
{
  virtual void visit(       T& v ){ static_cast<Derived*>(this)->visit(v); }
  virtual void visit( const T& v ){ static_cast<Derived*>(this)->visit(v); }
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class ABCVisitor
: public IVisitor< class A, class B, class C >
{  };

class ABC : public IVisitable< ABCVisitor >
{};

class A : public Visitable<A>::extends<ABC> {};
class B : public Visitable<B>::extends<ABC> {};
class C : public Visitable<C>::extends<B>   {};

int main()
{
  auto p = [](const auto& v){ std::cout << typeid(v).name() << std::endl; };
  auto printer = ABC::adaptVisitor( p );
  A a; B b; C c;
  std::vector< ABC* > vs{ &a, &b, &c };
  for( const auto& v : vs )
    v->accept(printer);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if this is what you are looking for, but here it goes. 
I would make the `accept` method of the base classes templated so that they can accept any visitor as long as the visitor has the right concept. In particular:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class Derived>
struct Base {

    // templated visitor so that it can take any argument as long as it has the right concept
    template <class Visitor>
    void accept(Visitor& visitor) {
        visitor.visit(static_cast<Derived&>(*this));
    }
};

struct T1
: Base<T1> {};

struct T2
: Base<T2> {};

struct T3
: Base<T3> {};

struct Visitor1 {

    void visit(T1& t1) {
        std::cout << "Visiting T1 from Visitor1" << std::endl;
    }

    void visit(T2& t2) {
        std::cout << "Visiting T2 from Visitor1" << std::endl;
    }
};


struct Visitor2 {

    void visit(T1& t1) {
        std::cout << "Visiting T1 from Visitor2" << std::endl;
    }

    void visit(T2& t2) {
        std::cout << "Visiting T2 from Visitor2" << std::endl;
    }

    void visit(T3& t3) {
        std::cout << "Visiting T3 from Visitor2" << std::endl;
    }
};




int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Visitor1 visitor1;
    Visitor2 visitor2;
    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;
    T3 t3;
    t1.accept(visitor1);
    t1.accept(visitor2);
    t2.accept(visitor1);
    t2.accept(visitor2);
    t3.accept(visitor2);
//    t3.accept(visitor1); // triggers a compilation error as visitor1 cannot handle T3 types
}
```

This way you no longer have to do any casts of your visitor classes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to cast to visitor with permuted parameters to accomplish what you want, the only thing you need is additional level of abstraction - variadic template wrapper to your visitor. Find the code below:

```
struct VisitorParent {
   virtual ~VisitorParent() = default;
};

template <class T>
struct VisitorImpl: virtual VisitorParent {
    virtual void visit(T &t) {
       //...
    }
};

template <class... Ts>
struct Visitor: virtual VisitorImpl<Ts>... { };

template <class T>
struct VisitorWrapperImpl {
   VisitorParent *vp;
   VisitorWrapperImpl(VisitorParent *vp): vp(vp) {}
   void visit(T &t) {
      VisitorImpl<T> *cvi = dynamic_cast<VisitorImpl<T> *>(vp);
      if (cvi) {
         cvi->visit(t);
      }
   }
};

template <class... Ts>
struct VisitorWrapper: VisitorWrapperImpl<Ts>... {
   VisitorWrapper(VisitorParent *vp): VisitorWrapperImpl<Ts>(vp)... { }
   template <class T>
   void visit(T &t) {
      VisitorWrapperImpl<T>::visit(t);
   }
};

int main() {
   Visitor<int, char, float> v;
   VisitorWrapper<char,float> vw(&v);
   char c;
   vw.visit(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be to have the accept method taking one of the base classes of the visitor. This way you can pass any visitor to the accept method since all visitors can be casted to the single base visitor class. I believe this will work for you:

```
#include <iostream>

// one of the base classes of your concrete visitors
template <class T>
struct VisitorUnit {

    virtual void visit(T& t) = 0;
};

// the visitor interface which will be implemented by concrete visitors
template <class... T>
struct Visitor
: VisitorUnit<T>... {

};

// the base class of your leaf classes
template <class Derived>
struct Base {

    void accept(VisitorUnit<Derived>& visitor) {
        visitor.visit(static_cast<Derived&>(*this));
    }
};

struct T1: Base<T1>{};
struct T2: Base<T2>{};
struct T3: Base<T3>{};

struct Visitor1
: Visitor<T1, T2, T3> {

    void visit(T1& t) override {
        std::cout << "T1 from Visitor1" << std::endl;
    }

    void visit(T2& t) override {
        std::cout << "T2 from Visitor1" << std::endl;
    }

    void visit(T3& t) override {
        std::cout << "T3 from Visitor1" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Visitor2
: Visitor<T3, T2> {


    void visit(T2& t) override {
        std::cout << "T2 from Visitor2" << std::endl;
    }

    void visit(T3& t) override {
        std::cout << "T3 from Visitor2" << std::endl;
    }
};



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;
    T3 t3;
    Visitor1 visitor1;
    Visitor2 visitor2;

    visitor1.visit(t1);
    visitor1.visit(t2);
    visitor1.visit(t3);

    visitor2.visit(t2);
    visitor2.visit(t3);


}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this wouldn't do as T1, T2 and T3 need to derive from single base class. I need them to so I can use type erasure.

Comment: @tsuki: you mentioned that you are using CRTP for the accept method, which is what I have used above. How have you implemented it?

Comment: I posted the answer.